# How to override User selections in Select2 tagbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

My question relates to Select2 selections displayed in the tagbox (I am not referring to the options in the dropdown).  My select2 works well, but I want to override User selections with jquery.  To do this I'd like to clear the tagbox of the User original selections and add, one by one, the selections of my choosing. The problem is that when I clear the tagbox, using $('#dropList').val([""]...  nothing seems to work.  The Fiddle example shows 'Earth' and 'Wind' already selected.  After clicking 'show buttons' I'd like to add, say 'Wind' on its own, or 'Wind' and 'Fire'.  But it's almost like the code can't deal with an empty tagbox. Any ideas much appreciated. http://jsfiddle.net/03aocump/

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js


<select id="dropList" style="width:300px" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Earth">Earth</option>
  <option value="Wind">Wind</option>
  <option value="Fire">Fire</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<button id='panel' >Show buttons</button>
<div id="target">
  <button  id='buttonWind' class='buttonstyle' type="button">Click for Wind</button>
  <button  id='buttonFire' class='buttonstyle' type="button">Click for Fire</button> 
</div>




//Initial value (imagine this has been as entered by User)
$("#dropList").select2();
$('#dropList').val(["Earth","Wind"]).trigger('change.select2');

// ---------------------

// Here we override the User selection
$('#panel').click(function() {
    $('#target').show();

$('#dropList').val([""]).trigger('change.select2');  // Clears tagbox but stops rest of code working!

$('#buttonWind').on('click',function() {
  var sel=$('#dropList').val();
  sel.push("Wind");
  $('#dropList').val(sel).trigger('change.select2');
})

$('#buttonFire').on('click',function() {
  var sel=$('#dropList').val();
  sel.push("Fire");
  $('#dropList').val(sel).trigger('change.select2');
})

});




body {padding:30px;}

#target {
  display: none;
  background:yellow;
  height:30px;
  width:320px;
  padding:15px;
}

.buttonstyle{
  width:150px;
  height:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is on this line repeated in *buttonWind* and *buttonFire*:

```
var sel=$('#dropList').val()
```

When you clear the content the previous line retuns null. This means you must convert this null to an empty array:

```
var sel=$('#dropList').val() || [];
```

This will solve your issue ([the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/03aocump/2/)):

```js
$("#dropList").select2();
$('#dropList').val(["Earth","Wind"]).trigger('change.select2');

// ---------------------

// Here we override the User selection
$('#panel').click(function() {
    $('#target').show();

    $('#dropList').val([""]).trigger('change.select2');

    $('#buttonWind').on('click',function() {
        var sel=$('#dropList').val() || [];
        sel.push("Wind");
        $('#dropList').val(sel).trigger('change.select2');
    })

    $('#buttonFire').on('click',function() {
        var sel=$('#dropList').val() || [];
        sel.push("Fire");
        $('#dropList').val(sel).trigger('change.select2');
    })

});
```

```css
body {padding:30px;}

#target {
    display: none;
    background:yellow;
    height:30px;
    width:320px;
    padding:15px;
}

.buttonstyle{
    width:150px;
    height:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select id="dropList" style="width:300px" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="Earth">Earth</option>
    <option value="Wind">Wind</option>
    <option value="Fire">Fire</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<button id='panel' >Show buttons</button>
<div id="target">
    <button  id='buttonWind' class='buttonstyle' type="button">Click for Wind</button>
    <button  id='buttonFire' class='buttonstyle' type="button">Click for Fire</button>
</div>
```

Comment: that's brilliant!  I wasn't aware of the need to convert to empty array.  Very much appreciated.